# Operadores inválidos numa expressão binária C

Tags: c

Tenho aqui um problema estou a tentar calcular a média no meu vetor `class_points`, mas ele me dá um erro e não sei como resolver. Alguém me poderia iluminar um pouco as ideias?

```
int better_than_average(int class_points[], int class_size, int your_points) {
  // Your code here :)
  // Note: class_size is the length of class_points.

  your_points = 80;

  class_points[class_size++] = your_points;

  int class_average = class_points div class_size;



  for (int i; i < class_size; i++)
  {
    if (your_points > class_average)
    {
      printf("True");
    } else {
      printf("False");
    }
  }
 }
```

Output do Clang 3.6 / C11

```
solution.c:9:35: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
  int class_average = class_points div class_size;
                                  ^
                                  ;
1 error generated.
```

Comment: De onde você tirou esse `div`? Acho que o que você queria era usar `/` no lugar dele. Em C, a divisão de inteiros é uma divisão inteira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O objetivo desse código é saber se uma nota está abaixo ou acima da nota média de um conjunto de notas. No entanto, há alguns pontos a se considerar:

- Não existe operador `div` em C. Use o operador `/` de divisão.
- Não faz sentido a média ser inteira.
- A sua forma de calcular a média está errada. Não tem sentido dividir um array por um número. O que teria sentido seria somar todos os elementos do array e dividir o resultado por um número ou então dividir o valor de todos os elementos do array por um mesmo número.
- Se você está atribuindo `your_points = 80;` logo no início da função, então o último parâmetro não estaria servindo para nada.
- Uma coisa é calcular a média e dizer se uma nota está acima ou abaixo dela e outra coisa bem diferente é colocar um valor novo em um array. Se o nome da função diz que ela faz uma coisa, ela não deveria fazer nada mais do que o que ela diz fazer. Essa função não deveria alterar o array dado.
- Esse `for` está errado, ele não está calculando nada. Está apenas comparando a nota 80 com cada uma das notas dadas no array e produzindo uma sequência de `True` e `False` sem nem olhar para a média calculada (seja ela o que for).
- Se a função retorna um `int`, então ela deveria ter um `return` em algum lugar.

O que você precisa para arrumar isso é simples:

1. Somar todos os elementos do array.

   ```
   int sum(int nums[], int size) {
     int total = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       total += nums[i];
     }
     return total;
   }
   ```
2. Calcular a média ao dividir o somatório dos elementos do array pelo tamanho do array.

   ```
   double average(int nums[], int size) {
     return sum(nums, size) / (double) size;
   }
   ```
3. Verificar se a sua nota está acima ou abaixo da média:

   ```
   int better_than_average(int nums[], int size, int your_points) {
     return your_points > average(nums, size);
   }
   ```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação!